# Calculating Cumulative Values MDX

Tags: mdx, cumulative-sum

I was trying to calculate cumulative values for the measure Closed WIT History
for the Month level, but had no luck

This is the Time dimension I have:

[image: Dimensions]

And this is my query:

```
WITH MEMBER [MEASURES].[Sales To Date]

AS

Sum

(



PeriodsToDate([DWH Dim Date].[(All)]),[Measures].[Closed WIT History]



)

SELECT

   {[Measures].[Closed WIT History], [MEASURES].[Sales To Date]} ON COLUMNS,

   [DWH Dim Date].[Month Name].[Month Name].Members ON ROWS

FROM [CUBE_Rel_1_AED_SAFe]

where [DWH Dim Date].[Year].&[2018]
```

But, for some reason, I get these results:

[image: results]

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried this Query:

```
WITH

 MEMBER [MEASURES].[Sales To Date] as

 SUM(

      {[DWH Dim Date].CurrentMember.Level.Members}.Item(0):[DWH Dim Date].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Closed WIT History]

         )





SELECT

   {[Measures].[Closed WIT History],[Measures].[Sales To Date]} ON COLUMNS,

   [DWH Dim Date].[Month Name].[Month Name].Members ON ROWS

FROM [CUBE_Rel_1_AED_SAFe]

where [DWH Dim Date].[Year].&[2018]
```

But then I get error like so:

[image: error in the calculated column]

Comment: And what are you trying to output?

Answer (score 1):

You could click on #Error to see the  detailed information. In addition, you also could use expression like below to achieve your goal

with member[Measures].[S2] AS
  sum(
      {[Date].[Month Name].&[2005]&[January]:[Date].[Month Name].CurrentMember} 
    , [Measures].[Internet Sales Count])

select nonempty ([Date].[Month Name].[Month Name].members) on rows, nonempty ({[Measures].[S2],[Measures].[Internet Sales Count]}) on columns from [Analysis Services Tutorial]

[image]

Zoe